# What is the word for the plastic cover you so often see protecting products?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I wondered what's the appropriate term for the hard plastic cover one so often sees protecting certain products. I took a photo in order to visualise my meaning:

[image: photo]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 'Hard plastic cover / protective packaging' works.

Comment: 'Molded plastic packaging' (See images here: https://www.google.com/search?q=molded+plastic+packaging&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR_7zS4fjaAhXHPI8KHUbnCZ8QsAQIJw&biw=1366&bih=654)

Comment: Are you referring to the translucent pieces of hard plastic protecting the tips of the knives, or the transparent plastic around all the knives?

Comment: @Lawrence referring the the overall packaging, not the plastic tips

Answer (score 4):

If the plastic is folded back on itself and then sealed at the edges, you may have a **clamshell package**. If the plastic is bonded to a piece of cardboard, then it’s a blister package, as mentioned by Jim Mack.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamshell_(container)

Comment: I gave a plus 1 but after some thought I think more caution might be needed - 'sealed clamshell' perhaps?

Comment: I looked at http://www.serpapackaging.com/ to see if there was a trade name.  It's a very interesting site, since they have videos of all their packing machines in operation.  I didn't find a specific device for the heat-sealed clamshell.

Answer (score 2):

This is often called a ***[blister pack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blister_pack)*** as seen at this Wikipedia page.

Comment: Blister packs are specifically for multiple instances of small single capsules of a medication. The OP is asking about the packaging of a medium sized manufactured consumer item, like  the knives as shown or batteries or small electronics or lots of things, annoyingly difficult to open.

Comment: @Mitch - That's one use. Look at the portion of the Wiki article labeled "Consumer goods".

Comment: @mitch, the "blister pack" term generally applies to any plastic shell with depth to hold the product, against a flat back.  The pill conformation you describe happens to be one kind of blister pack.  +1 to this answer, as it would have been my answer

Comment: @user662852, Jim: I had only ever thought of blister packs as those things like for medications that had little bubbles, like blisters, that you push a little pill out of, not for the large things.